# How to add a "small caps" style for the TinyMCE Advanced editor to use the style in the "Styles" dropdown tool in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

The Mystique theme includes two files that need to be updated to allow a custom styles section. The addition of a "small caps" style for use in the correct formatting of law journal citations. What is the steps to add a "small caps" style for the TinyMCE Advanced editor to use the style in the "Styles" dropdown tool in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Using TinyMCE 4, the following custom setup function will add a SmallCaps control:

```
setup: function (ed) {
    //Adds smallcaps button to the toolbar
    ed.addButton('smallcaps', {
        title: 'Smallcaps',
        icon: 'forecolor',
        onclick: function (evt) {
            ed.focus();
            ed.undoManager.beforeChange();//Preserve highlighted area for undo
            ed.formatter.toggle('smallcaps');
            ed.undoManager.add();//Add an undo point
        },
        onPostRender: function () {
            var ctrl = this;
            ed.on('NodeChange', function (e) {
                //Set the state of the smallcaps button to match the state of the selected text.
                ctrl.active(ed.formatter.match('smallcaps'));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Goetz is not complete, since TinyMCE does not know about your "user defined format" if you don't define it explicitly. Maybe it did some years ago, but version 4.7.x doesn't seem to do so. Add the code below in addition to his answer (it maybe needs to be bevore *setup*):

```
formats: {
    smallcaps: {
      inline: 'span',
      styles: {
        'font-variant': 'small-caps'
      },
      attributes: {
        title: 'smallcaps'
      }
    },
  },
  toolbar: 'smallcaps_button'
```

I prefer naming the formats and buttons slightly differently by suffixes like *_button* or *_format*, but that actually should not be a problem. Hence it avoids forgetting about to correctly define all needed parts here (`format`, `toolbar`, `ed.addButton()`). So, my `toolbar` contains the button *smallcaps_button* and the function is *ed.addButton('smallcaps_button')*

That's it.